# Почему Angular HttpClient не отправляет запросы?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular

У меня есть проект на `AngularJs`. Скажу что проект я не написал с нуля, и очень мало знаю `Angular`.

Вот хочу один простой `http` запрос сделать на сервер. И дело в том что запрос вообще не работает. Не дает никаких ошибок. **КАК БУДТО ЭТИ СТРОЧКИ КОДА ВООБЩЕ НЕ НАПИСАНЫ**.

До и после кода делаю логи все работает. Код залил в `try - catch` и опять никакой ошибки нету.

Кто то может подсказать что я делаю не так? И по какому пути мне идти?

Вот сам код.

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {ResultsFacade} from '../../../results/results.facade';
import {Company} from '../../../company/model/company.model';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-table',
  templateUrl: './people.table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people.table.component.css']
})
export class PeopleTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private resultsFacade: ResultsFacade, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  getData(result): void {
    console.log(`${environment.api_url}/company/data-details/${result.id}`);
    try {
      this.httpClient.post(`${environment.api_url}/company/data-details/${result.id}`, {}).pipe(
          map( (response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
          }));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    console.log(2222222222);
  }
}
```

А вот то что выводится в логе. А в ՝network՝ в браузере ничего нет. Никакого запроса.

Вот лог и `network`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если нет подписчиков Observer не выполняется

Comment: @Grundy можно немного конкретнее ? я вообще то `Backend` делаю, но эту часть фронта пришлось трогать.

Comment: [The code inside new Observable(function subscribe(subscriber) {...}) represents an "Observable execution", a lazy computation that **only happens** for each Observer **that subscribes**.](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#executing-observables)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое. Помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указано в [документации](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#executing-observables): `Observables` вычисляются лениво, и начинают что-то делать **только** при вызове `subscribe`.

Таким образом вместо `map` в данном случае нужно было использовать `.subscribe`

```
this.httpClient
    .post(`${environment.api_url}/company/data-details/${result.id}`, {})
    .subscribe(response => console.log(response))
```